# Merge two hasOne relation in laravel - Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have two table one is product and secound is RelatedProduct
where related product is connected with products.id and sometime with product.parent_id

```
public function relationWithId()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\RelatedProduct', 'product_id', 'id');
}

public function relationWithParent()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\RelatedProduct', 'product_id', 'parent_id');
}
```

so need a third relation where I can merge above both like this

```
public function relationProduct()
{
   /*****/
}


Product::where('status', '=', 'active')->with('relationProduct')->get();
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the accessor which merges the two relationship and returns the collections.

```
public function getRelatedProductAttribute($value){

    $withId = $this->relationWithId;
    $withParentId = $this->relationWithParent;

    return $withId->push($withParentId);
}
```

Comment: When I use
Product::where('status', '=', 'publish')->with('getRelatedProductAttribute')->get();
is it works ?

Comment: No, I think so. Try like this `$products->related_product;`